# Spring Security SAML error logging throws an error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, adfs2.0

I am new to SAML as well as spring security. I have configured the sample app to connect to an ADFS server following the documentation. When I access the app, I get redirected to the ADFS server appropriately, but one I enter my username and password, I get an error back in the app stating that there was an error validating the SAML message.

In an attempt to see why this is happening, I enabled the message logging according to the documentation (enabling the three properties in the samlLogger bean). When I do that, I get the following stacktrace on startup:

> Sep 17, 2018 11:56:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   listenerStart SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to
>   listener instance of class
>   [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4' while
>   setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [4]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataGeneratorFilter' while
>   setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'metadataGeneratorFilter' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml]: Cannot create
>   inner bean
>   'org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator#3aca2643'
>   of type [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator]
>   while setting constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator#3aca2643':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.setSamlEntryPoint(org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setSamlLogger(org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLLogger);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'samlLogger' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml]: Error setting property
>   values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'logAllMessages' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger]: Bean
>   property 'logAllMessages' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:988)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1860)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#4':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean 'metadataGeneratorFilter' while
>   setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'metadataGeneratorFilter' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml]: Cannot create
>   inner bean
>   'org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator#3aca2643'
>   of type [org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator]
>   while setting constructor argument; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator#3aca2643':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator.setSamlEntryPoint(org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'samlEntryPoint': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public void
>   org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.setSamlLogger(org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLLogger);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'samlLogger' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml]: Error setting property
>   values; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid
>   property 'logAllMessages' of bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger]: Bean
>   property 'logAllMessages' is not writable or has an invalid setter
>   method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of
>   the getter?
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>           ... 30 more

```
    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger">
    <!-- Enable these to see the actual SAML Messages in logs -->
    <property name="logAllMessages" value="true"/>
    <property name="logErrors" value="true"/>
    <property name="logMessagesOnException" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Any help please.

Thanks

Shaun

Comment: Any code please.

Comment: Literally just enabling the properties in securityContext.xml  <br>  `   <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger">
     <!-- Enable these to see the actual SAML Messages in logs -->
        <!-- <property name="logAllMessages" value="true"/> -->
        <!-- <property name="logErrors" value="true"/> -->
        <!-- <property name="logMessagesOnException" value="true"/> -->
 </bean>`

Comment: better update your question rather than posting here in comments

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of `Bean property 'logAllMessages' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?` is the use of a previous version of the library.

Up to release **1.0.3.RELEASE**, the property `logAllMessages` was called `logMessages`, and the property `logMessagesOnExeception` was not present.

```
public class SAMLDefaultLogger implements SAMLLogger {

private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SAMLDefaultLogger.class);

private boolean logMessages = false;
private boolean logErrors = true;
```

https://github.com/spring-attic/spring-security-saml/blob/1.0.3.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/log/SAMLDefaultLogger.java

The correct code for older releases is thus

```
<bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger">
<!-- Enable these to see the actual SAML Messages in logs -->
<property name="logMessages" value="true"/>
<property name="logErrors" value="true"/>
```